# Looking for an ePub reader that works without an SD card

Tags: applications, ebook-reader, epub

I'm looking for a ePub reader to read a collection of .epub files I have but so far each one I've tried has had problems because [I don't have an SD card in my phone](http://www.mobilecrunch.com/2010/12/06/surprise-the-nexus-s-has-no-microsd-slot-do-you-care/) or I haven't been able to figured out how to get it to read a file that I uploaded to the device.

*Anyone know of anything I can use?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming, you have a Nexus, the internal memory should show up as a normal SD card would in other phones. When you connect your phone to a PC and then MOUNT it, it ought to show up as a removable drive.

You can use [Aldiko](http://www.aldiko.com/) - it's an eBook reader (currently freeware) that works well with epubs.

- Copy the .epub file and drop it in your phone (after mounting)
- Place the .epub file in * phone_directory/ebooks/import
- Unmount, and start Aldiko
- Press the menu key, and hit import, give it some time to copy the file, and you're done!

The newly imported book should now show up on your bookshelf.

The [official FAQ](http://www.aldiko.com/support.html#faq987438943) might also help.

---

EDIT: An alternative (**easier**) method using the same app, available on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aldiko.android).

I found that I could import the .epub without connecting the device to a PC. This was verified with a Nexus 7, which does not have an SD card.

- Navigate to Aldiko's main page. After selecting Files, you can browse the files on your device.
- Select the .epub file you want to read and select Import.
- The .epub will show up in the Aldiko library.